# Use a column from the table itself for lookup row source query condition

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

In the design view of a table, in the Lookup tab, I'm entering the Row Source query. Is there some way to refer to the columns of the table itself when specifying a `where` condition? For example,

```
select [footable].[foreign] from [footable] where [footable].[id] = [self].id;
```

I've long been confused on this point.

---

Edit: to clarify with an example, let's say that the table that I'm currently editing has the name `bartable`, and I'm creating a row source for the dropdown for one of its columns called `baz`. In that dropdown I want to show the rows of `select [foreign] from [footable] inner join [bartable] on [footable].[id]=[bartable].[id]`, but not to *all* results of that join using all rows of `bartable` - rather, using the `id` value from the `bartable` *row for which the dropdown is currently being displayed*. So if the user clicked the dropdown for a `bartable` row in the `baz` column, and that row had an `id` of 23, it would show all `[footable].[foreign]` where their corresponding `[footable].[id]` is 23.

I hope that's more clear.

Comment: I am still not getting why you need to put join there???
your question says that you need only where condition there where you have to put `footable.id = [dropdown].[id] `

Comment: Even if I don't have a join and only have a where, it still doesn't work.

Comment: check whether you are getting currect value with currect datatype..

e.g. it may be because you would get ID in string from front end and in back end ID is of number...

second check whether you are checking with currect variable or not..
e.g. you want to check with dropdown variable and by mistake comparing with any other front end object values..

third think check you have to put index also, like in  array, so make sure you are giving index as well...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare same column it will give you all rows...
there is no difference in this type of condition or `where 1=1`

please check what condition exectly you want to put there..
or if from other source you are getting desired `id` then comment or edit your question accordingly..

Comment: I don't want to compare the same column. I want the row source to display entries from a different table whose `where` condition uses a value from the current row for which the dropdown is being displayed.

Comment: ohhh means this is not from the same table as you have questioned... ultimately you wanna to check for a outsourced value... right?? (from drop down you are fatching this other id value) then what is the problem you have in this case ??
I think i didn't understand your query properly..
can you please tell in examples..

Answer (score 0):

I just came to this page looking for an answer to the same question.

First, some clarification of the question (since there seems to be some confusion). You have a Bar Table that has a foreign key relationship to a Foo Table. When you click on the "baz" column in the Bar Table, you get a drop-down showing *every* row in the Foo Table. You don't want to show every row in the Foo Table; you want to show some subset of those rows selected according to some piece of information you already have in the Bar Table row.

In my case, I wanted to do this because both Bar and Foo have a foreign key relationship to a third table, Quux. When I use the drop-down in the "baz" column of Bar, I want only the rows in Foo that link to the same row in Quux that the row in Bar links to.

This worked for me in Access 2007:

```
SELECT [Foo].[PrimaryKey] FROM Foo WHERE [Foo].[ForeignKey to Quux]=[Bar].[ForeignKey to Quux];
```

Answer (score -1):

use the "CurrentRecord" property, e.g.

```
select [footable].[foreign]
from [footable], [bartable] 
where [footable].[id] = [bartable.fk]
and [bartable.id] = [CurrentRecord];
```

"bartable" is the table where you enter the "Row Source" query in the lookup tab

Comment: [CurrentRecord] always returns 1, does not matter on which record my cursor is